# Trouble with removing nodes in single linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Trouble with single linked list

So I was doing the removing node for single linked list, I made 3 functions but somehow it created infinite data although it deletes the data I need. Here is my code:

```
Node delHead(Node head){
    if(head==NULL){
        printf("There is nothing to delete!");
    }
    else{
        head=head->next;
    }
    return head;
}

Node delTail(Node head){
    if(head==NULL||head->next==NULL){
        return delHead(head);
    }else{
        Node p = head;
        Node prev = NULL;
        while(p->next !=NULL){
            prev=p;
            p=p->next;
        }
        prev->next= NULL;
        free(p);
        return head;
    }
}
Node delAt(Node head, int position){
    if(position == 0 || head == NULL || head->next == NULL){
        head = delHead(head); 
    }else{
        int k = 0;
        Node p = head;
        Node prev = NULL;
        while(p != NULL && k != position){
            prev = p;
            p=p->next;
            k++;
        }
        if(k != position){
            head = delTail(head);
        }else{
            prev->next=p->next;
            free(p);
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

I'm using visual studio code, so I hope someone can fix me with this. I try p->next->next but it didn't work out so appreciate you guys so much. Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: @Bùi Mạnh Huym "somehow it created infinite data " --> post the code that demonstrates,  A [mcve].

Comment: "it didn't work" is not sufficient as a problem description. Show the error you get or the actual and expected output. Where exactly did you try `p->next->next`? This is undefined behavior if `p->next` is not a valid pointer to a node. [Edit] your question to add information.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another comment, you should have provided an example of how you code and the output it gave you. I only noticed 1 issue, you were using a **Node** instead of a **Node*** for your paramaters, return values, and local variables. I changed the code and validated that your original functions were correct.

> **Tip 1:** You can only use the arrow notation **StructPtr->variable** if you are referencing a pointer, otherwise you have to use the dot notation **Struct.variable**

> **Tip 2:** You can only set a pointer equal to NULL. This means that you can set **Node* node** to NULL, but you cannot set **"Node node"** equal to NULL

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

Node* delHead(Node* head);
Node* delTail(Node* head);
Node* delAt(Node* head, int position);
void displayNode(Node* head, char* type);

int main()
{
    Node* head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* tmpNext = head;
    
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--){
        tmpNext->data = i;
        tmpNext->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tmpNext = tmpNext->next;
    }
    tmpNext->next = NULL;
    
    displayNode(head, "Original");
    
    tmpNext = head;
    tmpNext = delHead(tmpNext);
    displayNode(tmpNext, "Delete Head");
    
    tmpNext = head;
    tmpNext = delTail(tmpNext);
    displayNode(tmpNext, "Delete Tail");
    
    tmpNext = head;
    tmpNext = delAt(tmpNext, 3);
    displayNode(tmpNext, "Delete at 3");

    return 0;
}


Node* delHead(Node* head){
    if(head==NULL){
        printf("There is nothing to delete!");
    }
    else{
        head=head->next;
    }
    return head;
}

Node* delTail(Node* head){
    if(head==NULL||head->next==NULL){
        return delHead(head);
    }else{
        Node* p = head;
        Node* prev = NULL;
        while(p->next !=NULL){
            prev=p;
            p=p->next;
        }
        prev->next= NULL;
        free(p);
        return head;
    }
}

Node* delAt(Node* head, int position){
    if(position == 0 || head == NULL || head->next == NULL){
        head = delHead(head); 
    }else{
        int k = 0;
        Node* p = head;
        Node* prev = NULL;
        while(p != NULL && k != position){
            prev = p;
            p=p->next;
            k++;
        }
        if(k != position){
            head = delTail(head);
        }else{
            prev->next=p->next;
            free(p);
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void displayNode(Node* head, char* type){
    printf("\n%s:\n", type);
    while(head->next != NULL){
        printf("[%d]", head->data);
        head = head->next;
        if(head->next != NULL)
            printf(" -> ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original:
[9] -> [8] -> [7] -> [6] -> [5] -> [4] -> [3] -> [2] -> [1] -> [0]

Delete Head:
[8] -> [7] -> [6] -> [5] -> [4] -> [3] -> [2] -> [1] -> [0]

Delete Tail:
[9] -> [8] -> [7] -> [6] -> [5] -> [4] -> [3] -> [2] -> [1]

Delete at 3:
[9] -> [8] -> [7] -> [5] -> [4] -> [3] -> [2] -> [1]
```